# I need a driver but i dont know where to get the one i need

Tags: release-hera, drivers

Processor: Intel Atom x5-Z8350 CPU @ 1.44GHz
Memory: 2GB of DDR3
Graphics: CPU Integrated 
Tablet Model Number: RCA W101SA23T1

I need the driver for the Intel SST Audio Device (WDM) and the Realtek I2S Audio Codec But I don't know where to get them, I found a guide made for Ubuntu but to no avail (which doesn't make sense because Elementary OS is based off Ubuntu.) Does anyone know where to get the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Elementary is based on Ubuntu and Debian, so you are wrong. Install dkms in terminal
sudo apt install dkms

Install deb from 18.04 or 19. 04 using Eddy.

https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

Additionally I am not sure is it a driver for your Realtek, but it works with really old kernel.

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software

Additionally you can check the solution from Mint forum which should also work.

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by install deb from 18.04 or 19.04 using eddy none of the files under 18.04 or 19.04 end in .deb is there a special program i use or is the .deb file inside of the .tar.gz file?

Comment: Eddy is a software which you can install from App Center. Then you can just open deb file in Eddy and install it. This is the non terminal way.

Comment: i know what eddy is but none of the files i see inside of the first link's page end in .deb

Comment: Right. I did not check it. But idea is simple, download, extract. Then go to the location where extracted directory is and open this place in terminal. Or cd /home/user/Downloads/audio then by default it should be there a config file. I do not check it, just because you should know how to compile from source. Anyway the idea is simple.  ./configure && make && sudo make install